# SQlite3 + Python: How do I pull a record from a table using two specific strings?

Tags: python, sqlite, record

In my program, I'm trying to call a record in my database from two pieces of string input by the User

Here's the line I'm using, `Compliance = "Low"` and `Dialogue_Type = "Early Q"`, both are string in my database:

```
sqlite_select_query = ("SELECT * FROM Alpha WHERE Compliance LIKE '%{0}%' AND 'Dialogue Type' LIKE '%{1}%'".format(Compliance, Dialogue_Type))
```

I've tried using `=` and `LIKE` however it only returns `None`. I've also tried using actual string values:

```
sqlite_select_query = ("SELECT * FROM Alpha WHERE Compliance LIKE '%Low%' AND 'Dialogue Type' LIKE '%Early Q%'")
```

This also returns None, I know for a fact that these values ARE in my database. Can ya help me please?

Comment: Don't use single quotes around column names. Use backticks or square brackets: `[Dialogue Type]`

Comment: Also don't use `string.format` to bind literal values to SQL statements in Python. Use [parameterization](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html).